# how to calculate 2 hours from the time request made in seconds

Tags: php

My server time is GMT, so I convert it to Asia/Kuala Lumpur timing.I need to calculate time difference between current time and the time request was made. The time request was made is stored in database and retrieved in `$reset_req` variable.

```
$reset_req="2015-06-30 11:30:23";   

$timezone_offset = +8; // us central time (gmt-6) for me

if(isset($reset_req)){
 $request_date2 = strtotime($reset_req)+$timezone_offset*60*60;
}
echo "current time= ".strtotime(time());
echo"<br/>";
echo "time req made=".strtotime($request_date2);
echo"<br/>";
  $timediff = strtotime(time()) - strtotime($request_date2); // in seconds

if($timediff < 2 hours)//how to calculate 2 hours here
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting how many seconds there are in two hours?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, 7200 seconds I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone already said how to calculate 2 hours (2* 3600sec). But what they didn't tell you is that you can't do this: `strtotime(time());` `time();` already gives you a Unix timestamp so you can't convert it twice.

Your Code should look more like this

```
<?php

$reset_req = "2015-06-30 11:30:23";   

$timezone_offset = +8; // us central time (gmt-6) for me

if(isset($reset_req)){
      $request_date2 = strtotime($reset_req)+$timezone_offset*60*60;
      $current = time();
} else {
      echo '$reset_req was not set';
      exit;
}

echo "current time= " . $current . "<br />";
echo "time req made=" . $request_date2 . "<br />";

$timediff = $current - $request_date2; // in seconds

if($timediff < (2*3600))//how to calculate 2 hours here
{
    echo "less than 7200 sec have past since $request_date2. Past: $timediff seconds";    
}else{
    echo "more than 7200 sec have past since $request_date2. Past: $timediff seconds";   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hour = 3600; //an hour has 3600 seconds
if($timediff < 2 * $hour )
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining why and how this code snippet does answer the OP question

Answer (score 0):

$timediff is in seconds. So you have to convert that to hours or convert the 2 hours to seconds and then need to compare like as follows:

replace

```
if($timediff < 2 hours)//how to calculate 2 hours here
{
 //do something
}
```

with

```
if($timediff < (2*3600))//how to calculate 2 hours here
{
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$reset_req = "2015-06-30 11:30:23"; 

//set default timezone here
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");

$request_date2 = '';

if(isset($reset_req))
{
    $request_date2 = strtotime($reset_req);
}

echo "Current time = ".time();
echo"<br/>";
echo "Time req made =".$request_date2;
echo"<br/>";

$timediff = time() - $request_date2; // in seconds
echo "<br>Time Differnce : ".$timediff;

//how to calculate 2 hours here
if($timediff < 2*3600)
{
    //do something
}

?>
```